# Connection Positive Semi Definite matrices and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite, gradient-descent

During my math class my professor described the following situation in context of gradient descent methods:

Define $S = \{ x \in R^n : f(x) \leq f(x_0)\}$ and assume $f(x)$ is strongly convex in $S$. There is a contstant $m > 0$ with $\triangledown^2 f(x) \succcurlyeq mI$. He said something along the lines of "this means the smallest eigenvalue is larger than m". Can somebody explain why this is the case?

The curly braces mean that the less or equal is PSD in this context, but I don't see how that translates to eigenvalues. I don't see how $\forall v \in S, v^T (\triangledown^2 f(x) - mI )v \geq 0 $ means that the eigenvalues are larger than $m$. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Symmetric matrices have orthogonal eigenvectors, and if matrix is positive than eigenvalues are positive. This means that such matrix is diagonal with eigenvalues on the diagonal in the basis defined by its eigenvectors. Now, diagonal matrices with positive entries have minimum (on unit sphere) equal to the smallest value on the diagonal. This is easy to check computing $<Dx,x>$ for $D$ diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the precise statement should be that if the eigenvalues are at least $m$ then your inequality holds.  To frame it more generally, you want to show if $A$ is an $n\times n$ real symmetric matrix and the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ is at least $m$, then  $v'(A-mI)v\geq 0\quad\forall v\in\mathbb R^n$.

By the spectral theorem, symmetry of $A$ implies it is orthogonally diagonalizable, and hence has a spectral decomposition $A=Q'\Lambda Q$ where $Q'Q=I,\Lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$ and $\lambda_j$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Without loss, let's assume $\lambda_1\leq ...\leq \lambda_n$.
Then we have $\forall v\in\mathbb R^n$

$$ v'Av=(Qv)'\Lambda Qv=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j [(Qv)_j]^2\geq \lambda_1\sum_{j=1}^n [(Qv)_j]^2=\lambda_1 (Qv)'Qv=\lambda_1 v'v\geq mv'v.$$

Comment: This is an amazing explanation. Thank you.

Comment: No prob! pls upvote if you found it helpful

Comment: Tried to but I need more karma.